# Java/Spring - Save file button

Tags: java, spring, file-io

I want to make a code to bring data from the server and allow the user to save that data into a file in his/her PC.

I'm a beginner on this, so can you help me?

Comment: In a webapp, add a link to the html. But I suspect you're not writing a webapp?

Comment: StackOverflow is oriented towards concrete problems. This might get closed for being vague.

Comment: I tried first doing with JavaScript creating a document object variable, and using execCommand to save the data printed in a webpage. But the page becomes blank, and the data appears printed. It does allows me saving it into a text file, but I don't like that refresh it does to get the data.

What I want is to press the button, get a save file dialog, and get the data saved into text file without the page refreshing or anything.

Comment: madth3, I am writing a web app, indeed. What I want and tried is described above.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ResponseEntity](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/ResponseEntity.html) class to generate custom response, for example downloadable image or zip:

```
@RequestMapping("")
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> generateResponseEntity() {
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();

    headers.add("Content-Type", "application/zip");
    headers.add("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=zip.zip");

    return new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(getBytes(), headers, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```